# How to save r object output in python environment

Tags: python, sql, r, pandas

I’m working in the ipython environment, however I’m using r in that enviornment with r.objects

Now my question is: can I save the r.objects output in a text file so that I can read it?

```
Import rpy2.robjects as robjects
robjects.r.glm(....)
```

So I want to be able to see the output without the use of Jupyter notebook.  So I thought the best way to do that was to save the output as a text file. That’s why I was wondering how I could do that

Comment: Please see [here - credit to Jared Stufft](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/interfacing-r-from-python-3-jupyter-notebook-jared-stufft/). It may be a workaround, but you could pull the R object into your Python environment and write it to whatever file is necessary.

Comment: Why not print `summary` of `glm` object which is the way to see summary of model in R?